# which type i need for this input "06/09/2011 05:25" ? on the model ? (column type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm using this datetimepicker, http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ and i get this datetime input: 06/09/2011 05:25, now i want to save the input in the database so i can use it later, which column type i need to setup on the datebase?
i'm using this code for getting the input from users.

```
f.text_field :status_date
```

i tried the types date and datetime but both of them did not work (the column was nil when submiting)

thanks,
Gal